# Should you use an object as a method parameter for a method within that objects class?

Tags: java, methods

I am new to both Java programming and StackOverflow so apologies if this may sound trivial.

I have written a method within a class that within the logic, at times accesses a field value of an object from that same class.

From a convention point of view, would it be better to include the object as a parameter for the method? or to use the field name directly within the method and use dot notation to point to the object within the main method?

Example 1:

```
public class A
{
    private String name;


    public void method(A objectOne)
    {
        System.out.println(objectOne.name);
    }

}
```

Example 2:

```
public class A
{
    private String name;
    
    public void method()
    {
        System.out.println(name);
    }


    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        A test = new A();
        test.method();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Doing this would make sense in 2 main situations:

1. You compare the current object, `this`, with the parameter passed in. An example of this is the `Comparable<T>` interface where you have a method `public int CompareTo(T other)` where you add code that compares the two objects and returns an int that represents their ranking. ... or
2. The method is `static`. In your example, this would be a perfect example of where static would work well.

For example:

```
public class A implements Comparable<A> {
    private String name;

    public int compareTo(A other) {
            // uses String#compareTo method
            return this.name.compareTo(other.name);
    }
    
    public static void display(A other) {
        System.out.println(other.name);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless you somehow need access to *two* instances of the type, there's no reason whatsoever to have a non-static method of a class take an instance of that class as the argument. Using `this` is clearly the preferred way here.

Examples where you need two instances in the method (to compare them, specifically) are the `equals()` and `compareTo()` methods: they specifically compare two objects (for equality or for order, respectively). There it makes sense to pass the second one as an explicit argument.